# Javascript sorting of null values to be considered

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects which has null values also similar to the one below

```
let customerData = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'cust1',
        address: null
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'cust2',
        address: 'test1'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'cust3',
        address: 'add2'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'cust4',
        address: 'test2'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: 'cust5',
        address: null
    }
];
```

In asc/desc the null values are always sorted at the last.Can anyone please help me to sort the null values also?Either move all the null values to the top when asc/desc.

If we replace the null values by blank, the sorting works as expected.But we cannot change the data to empty as the null and empty values are treated differently.

I have seen many similar posts but all of them are making the null values to push below like the links below.

[How to sort an array with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684937/how-to-sort-an-array-with-null-values)

Please dont mark this question as duplicate as i couldn't find a proper solution.

The solutions i have tried

```
 data.sort(function (item1, item2) {
    ------------------/////---not working------------------------------
if (item1[colBinding] === null && sort.direction === 'asc') return 1;
if (item2[colBinding] === null && sort.direction === 'asc') return 0;
if (item1[sort.colBinding] === null && sort.direction === 'desc') return 1;                if (item2[sort.colBinding] === null && sort.direction === 'desc') return -1;
if (sort.direction === 'asc') return item1[sort.colBinding] > item2[sort.colBinding];
if (sort.direction === 'desc') return item1[sort.colBinding] < item2[sort.colBinding]; 

-------------------------------------------------------
----------------------//working to push null at the end 
let currentData = item1[colBinding] === null ? '' : item1[sort.colBinding];
let nextData = item2[sort.colBinding] === null ? '' : item2[sort.colBinding];
if (currentData === nextData) { return -1 };
if (currentData < nextData) { return 0 };
if (currentData > nextData) { return 1 };
 ----------------------------------------------------------

---------------------/// not working-----------------------------------
var nullPosition = sort.direction === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
if (item1[colBinding] === null) return nullPosition;
if (item2[colBinding] === null) return -nullPosition;
if (item1[colBinding] < item2[colBinding]) return -nullPosition;
if (item1[colBinding] > item2[colBinding]) return nullPosition;
return 0
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                });
```

Comment: format your code

Comment: The answer you linked to doesn't push below... It depends on the sort order... And you could edit it slightly if need be. Definitely a duplicate...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33684937/how-to-sort-an-array-with-null-values)

Comment: Do you understand what the comparison callback of `sort` does? Where you return `-1`, `0` or `1`? The question you link to pretty much already contains the answer, you just need to adjust when to return `-1` or `1` for your specific desired case.

Comment: Please see the edited code in which i have tried the solutions...

Comment: Hi @Salketer : As i have told, it might be a duplicate question of the same link you have provided, but i could'nt find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check the value for `null` first and sort them to top, then sort by the value.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'cust1', address: null }, { id: 2, name: 'cust2', address: 'test1' }, { id: 3, name: 'cust3', address: 'add2' }, { id: 4, name: 'cust4', address: 'test2' }, { id: 5, name: 'cust5', address: null }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.address === null) - (a.address === null) || ('' + a.address).localeCompare(b.address);
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For descending sort, just reverse the second part

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'cust1', address: null }, { id: 2, name: 'cust2', address: 'test1' }, { id: 3, name: 'cust3', address: 'add2' }, { id: 4, name: 'cust4', address: 'test2' }, { id: 5, name: 'cust5', address: null }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.address === null) - (a.address === null) || ('' + b.address).localeCompare(a.address);
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi , Thank you for sharing the answer.It helped me a lot. As i needed the null to display above in descending order, I have reversed the descending code as :- data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.address === null) - (b.address === null) || ('' + b.address).localeCompare(a.address);
});

Comment: the first part move `null` values to top or bottom. if the change is working for you, then it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom sort function to sort the array and use a parameter to specify the sorting order.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'cust1', address: null }, { id: 2, name: 'cust2', address: 'test1' }, { id: 3, name: 'cust3', address: 'add2' }, { id: 4, name: 'cust4', address: 'test2' }, { id: 5, name: 'cust5', address: null }];

var sortWithOrder = (data, order) => {
  let r = order === 'ASC' ? 1 : -1;
  return data.sort(function (a, b) {
  if(!a.address && !b.address)
    return 0;
  else if(!b.address && a.address)
    return 1;
  else if(!a.address && b.address)
    return -1;
  else
    return r * a.address.localeCompare(b.address);
  });
}

console.log(sortWithOrder(data, 'ASC'));
console.log(sortWithOrder(data, 'DESC'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```